# Assign PHP values inside JSON Array

Tags: php, html, json

Im working on this DUDAMOBILE API. Custom integration in PHP website. first it takes URL from customer.

```
$url = $_POST["url"]
```

and i want to assign this url in below code

```
$data = '
        {   
        "site_data":
            {               
                "original_site_url":"http://www.test.com/"
            }
        }
    ';
```

but not sure how to assign it to above code. i tried like this. but it doesn't work

```
$data = '
        {   
        "site_data":
            {               
                "original_site_url":'.$url.'
            }
        }
    ';
```

im getting this error
`Failed to parse JSON: Unexpected character ('h' (code 104))`

Comment: NO! don't create json string manually, use json encode, that's why this exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the value as well, otherwise it is no valid JSON string:

```
$data = '
        {   
        "site_data":
            {               
                "original_site_url":"'.$url.'"
            }
        }
    ';
```

The error is because the parser expects a double quote and finds an "h" of the beggining of the url (http....).

Comment: While the answer of kylehyde215 is more clean. If an answer works for you and you think it solves your problem you should mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the slashes in the url. It's better to use `json_encode` rather than trying to format the json by hand.

```
$data = ['site_data' => ['original_site_url' => $url]];
$json = json_encode($data); // json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) to keep formatting.
```

Comment: ah right. that is the code they gave me to download as API. so i didnt try to change it much